# Random em botão com isEmpty();

Tags: java, android, random

Olá, sou novo em programação to estudando Java e agora um pouco de Android. Estou tentando usar o `Random` para emitir mensagens aleatórias caso nada seja digitado. Então, meu código está assim:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText caixaTexto;
private Button botaoIdade;
private TextView resultadoIdade;
private String[] frases = {"Digite um número", "Digita logo o número", "Cara, digita logo isso"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    caixaTexto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.caixaTextoId);
    botaoIdade = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoIdadeId);
    resultadoIdade = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultadoIdadeId);

    botaoIdade.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //recuperar o que foi digitado
            String textoDigitado = caixaTexto.getText().toString();

            if(textoDigitado.isEmpty()){
                Random random = new Random();
                int numAleatorio = random.nextInt(frases.length);
                //String vazia receberá uma mensagem de erro
                resultadoIdade.setText(numAleatorio);

            }else{
                int valorDigitado = Integer.parseInt(textoDigitado);
                int resultadoFinal = valorDigitado * 7;

                resultadoIdade.setText("A idade do cachorro em anos humanos são: " +
                        resultadoFinal + " anos.");
            }
        }
    });
```

Tentei também usar isso dentro da ação do botão ao invés do `random`:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mensagem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Quando executo o programa no meu celular e aperto o botão para ver se sai alguma mensagem no TextView "resultado", dá erro e ele fecha.

Alguém pode explicar o que pode estar errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro, você só deveria criar o `Random` uma única vez e então reutilizá-lo:

```
private static final Random random = new Random();
```

Segundo, essa linha não deverá fazer o que você quer:

```
resultadoIdade.setText(numAleatorio);
```

Acho que deveria ser isso:

```
resultadoIdade.setText(frases[numAleatorio]);
```

Comment: Deu certo, valeu. Só não entendi porque não deu certo, porque eu joguei o array.length dentro do textoDigitado...enfim obrigado

Comment: @AndréSantos Se esta resposta te serviu, não se esqueá de marcá-la como correta/aceita ao clicar no ✅ verde do lado da resposta. Ocorre que `numAleatorio` e `array.length` são do tipo `int`, enquanto que `frases[numAleatorio]` e `textoDigitado` são do tipo `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Podes tentar substituir:

```
textoDigitado.isEmpty()
```

por

```
textoDigitado.equalsIgnoreCase("")
```